# 'Model' object is not iterable

Tags: python, python-3.x, django, django-2.0

Assim que clico em um button que chama minha view para editar a row da table em questão me mostra o erro: **'MeuModel' object is not iterable.**

- Estou usando o django 2.1.15
- Python 3.8.1
- Banco SQL server

views.py

```
def Alterar_Pessoa(request, id):
    visitantes = get_object_or_404(DadosPessoas, pk=id)
    form = PessoaForm(instance=visitantes)

    if(request.method == 'POST'):
        return False

    else:
        return render(request, 'portaria/cadastroPessoa.html', {'form': form, 'visitantes': visitantes})
```

Mensagem de erro completa:

```
TypeError at /portaria/alterarPessoa/18
'DadosPessoas' object is not iterable
Request Method: GET
Request URL:    http://127.0.0.1:8000/portaria/alterarPessoa/18
Django Version: 2.1.15
Exception Type: TypeError
Exception Value:    
'DadosPessoas' object is not iterable
Exception Location: C:\Users\leona\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python38\site-packages\django\template\defaulttags.py in render, line 165
Python Executable:  C:\Users\leona\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\python.exe
Python Version: 3.8.1
Python Path:    
['C:\\Users\\leona\\OneDrive\\Ambiente de '
 'Trabalho\\projeto\\MCS_JSP\\mcs\\MCS_Back',
 'C:\\Users\\leona\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python38-32\\python38.zip',
 'C:\\Users\\leona\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python38-32\\DLLs',
 'C:\\Users\\leona\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python38-32\\lib',
 'C:\\Users\\leona\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python38-32',
 'C:\\Users\\leona\\AppData\\Roaming\\Python\\Python38\\site-packages',
 'C:\\Users\\leona\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python38-32\\lib\\site-packages']
Server time:    Sex, 10 Abr 2020 13:21:14 -0300


Error during template rendering
In template C:\Users\leona\OneDrive\Ambiente de Trabalho\projeto\MCS_JSP\mcs\MCS_Back\portaria\templates\portaria\cadastroPessoa.html, error at line 372

Linha 372: {% for visitante in visitantes %}
```

Comment: coloca a mensagem de erro completa e a linha onde esta acusando o erro

Comment: Adicionei a mensagem e a linha

Comment: esse erro acusa que a variável visitantes não é iterável, ou seja o python não consegue executar o for loop nela. Qual é o tipo de dado de visitantes? executa um print(type(visitantes))

Answer (score 2):

Para popular a variável `visitantes` você esta usando [`get_object_or_404()`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/http/shortcuts/#get-object-or-404) que por traz dos panos fará um `get()` caso não encontre nada ele lançará Http404 ao invés de DoesNotExist.

O problema está no `get_object_or_404()` utilizar o `get()`. Isso é análogo a fazer:

```
DadosPessoas.objects.get(id=id)
```

O `get()` trará um objeto do tipo **DadosPessoas** pois ele esta fazendo uma busca direta pelo id. O objeto do tipo DadosPessoas não é, de fato, *iterable*.

Teria de ser usado então o `filter()` ao invés do `get()`.

O `filter()` retorna um objeto do tipo **QuerySet** que por sua vez é *iterable*. Dessa forma utilizando o:

```
visitantes = get_list_or_404(DadosPessoas, pk=id)
```

Por baixo dos panos será executado algo como:

```
DadosPessoas.objects.filter(id=id)
```

Retornando então um objeto com o tipo certo. Veja a documentação do [`get_list_or_404()`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/http/shortcuts/#get-list-or-404) e [exemplos](https://www.programcreek.com/python/example/50062/django.shortcuts.get_list_or_404).

Caso esteja lidando com dados provindos de **formulário** a forma de tratamento é completamente diferente e para isso recomenda-se o uso de [formsets](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/forms/formsets/).

Comment: Entendi o que estava causando o erro e antes mesmo de testar fez sentido pra mim e imaginei que funcionaria, porem ao testar recebi um novo erro: 'list' object has no attribute '_meta'

Comment: O que o método PessoaForm faz exatamente ? Se você estiver lidando com dados de formulário o ideal será usar [Formsets](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/forms/formsets/) Pelo erro que descreveu parece ser o caso.

Comment: Sim dados de formulários, vou tentar usar o Formsets então, não sei como mas eu vou tentar aprender